# Brackets in Regular Expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I'd like to compare 2 strings with each other, but I got a little problem with the Brackets.
The String I want to seek looks like this:

CAPPL:LOCAL.L_hk[1].vorlauftemp_soll

Quoting those to bracket is seemingly useless.

I tried it with this code

```
var regex = new RegExp("CAPPL:LOCAL.L_hk\[1\].vorlauftemp_soll","gi");
var value = "CAPPL:LOCAL.L_hk[1].vorlauftemp_soll";
regex.test(value);
```

Somebody who can help me??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is useless because you're using string. You need to escape the backslashes as well:

```
var regex = new RegExp("CAPPL:LOCAL.L_hk\\[1\\].vorlauftemp_soll","gi");
```

Or use a regex literal:

```
var regex = /CAPPL:LOCAL.L_hk\[1\].vorlauftemp_soll/gi
```

Unknown escape characters are ignored in JavaScript, so `"\["` results in the same string as `"["`.

Answer (score 2):

In `value`, you have `(1)` instead of `[1]`. So if you expect the regular expression to match and it doesn't, it because of that.

Another problem is that you're using `""` in your expression. In order to write regular expression in JavaScript, use `/.../g` instead of `"..."`.

You may also want to escape the dot in your expression. `.` means "any character that is not a line break". You, on the other hand, wants the dot to be matched literally: `\.`.

Comment: Very good points, though `new RegExp("a+","g")` is valid in JavaScript, and mandatory when you want to create a regex object dynamically (for example, using a string literal: `"\\[" + name + "\\["`).

Comment: I used "", because I tested the RegEx in a TryEditor.

Answer (score 1):

You are generating a regular expression (in which `[` is a special character that can be escaped with `\`) using a string (in which `\` is a special character).

```
var regex = /CAPPL:LOCAL.L_hk\[1\].vorlauftemp_soll/gi;
```