# Regex match list of strings that can contain spaces

Tags: regex

I'm using a regex expression to match from a list of strings:

```
/(Art|Dance|Writing|Theater \(Musical\))/g
```

The problem I'm running into is that single-word strings "Art", "Dance", "Writing", etc. match perfectly, but I can't figure out how to match "Theater (Musical)". Everything tip I've found is for matching *any* string that can contain spaces, but I need it to only be from the given list.

I believe the software we're using uses the javascript regex flavor, if that makes any difference.

Comment: just use \s for space

Comment: This question may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6015462/brackets-in-regular-expression

Comment: At first, that wasn't working either, then I realized I had the insensitive flag on. Leaving that off, it matches even without using \s. Why would the case insensitive flag affect spaces/word boundaries?

Comment: @Androbin `\s` matches any whitespace character.  including an actual space in the regex, as in the question, is the correct way to match a space.

Answer (score 4):

The regex in your question is correct and will match the input `Theater (Musical)`.

[Here it is in Regex 101](https://regex101.com/r/Z2ZjO5/1).

It also [will correctly match even if you have the `i` case insensitive flag set](https://regex101.com/r/e0lnsZ/1).  (Of course, it will also match `THEATER (mUsIcAl)` etc. in that case).

There must have been some other issue with your code or input data.